How to map the 3D skeleton joints back to 2D color image in ROS?
I am writing a callback function to map 3D skeletons back to 2D color image. The function subscribe the skeleton topic, and publish 2D pixel position of the joints.
Can I use this function k4a_calibration_3d_to_2d() for the mapping? If so, how should I define the parameters inside, especially k4a_calibration_t?
The camera is turn on by another launch file and camera_info is published. But there is only intrinsic value.

https://github.com/fsstudio-team/ZeroSimROSUnity
